# Using a custom format to parse numeric strings

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to know how to take numbers that are 12 digits long 123456789012 and have them display as 123 456 789 012. I apologize If that is explained in the Microsoft custom formats article but I couldn't make sense of it and would really appreciate it if someone could explain to me how to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format string is **### ### ### ### ###**

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you so much haha. I feel very foolish as I tried this before with cells that already had the strings in them. Since they didn't change I assumed I did something wrong. After reading your suggestion I tried that again but then double clicked into the cell and out again and sure enough it worked perfectly. I just don't trust myself sometimes. Couldn't have done it without you :)